# Debugging Quadratic Equation Grapher (Java)

Tags: java

I am currently attempting to debug some code for an assignment and have hit a wall, I realize that this isn't for just giving me the answer and as such am just looking for some help in the right direction. The program that was given to me is supposed to allow the user to graph various quadratic equations by using sliders to change the coefficients in the equation however when the b and c values are changed they always remain positive. It is also worth mentioning that the coefficients are displayed correctly at the top of the graph screen, just the graph is wrong.

```
//********************************************************************
//   Equation.java       Authors: Lewis/Loftus
//
//   Solution to Programming Project 10.9 
//********************************************************************

public class Equation
{
   private int a, b, c;
   public final String SQUARED = "\u00B2";

   //------------------------------------------------------------------
   //   Sets up the default coeficients of this equation:
   //   a*x^2 + b*x + c
   //------------------------------------------------------------------
   public Equation()
   {
      a = b = c = 0;
   }

   //------------------------------------------------------------------
   //   Sets up the coeficients of this equation as specified.
   //------------------------------------------------------------------
   public Equation (int aValue, int bValue, int cValue)
   {
      a = aValue;
      b = bValue;
      c = cValue;
   }

   //------------------------------------------------------------------
   //   Computes the current value of this equation.
   //------------------------------------------------------------------
   public double computeValue(double x)
   {
      return a*x*x + b*x + c;
   }

   //------------------------------------------------------------------
   //   Returns a string representation of this equation.
   //------------------------------------------------------------------
   public String toString()
   {
      StringBuffer equation = new StringBuffer();

      if (a==0 && b==0 && c==0)
         equation.append("0");
      else
      {
         if (a != 0)
         {
            if (a==-1)
               equation.append("-");
            else
               if (a!=1)
                  equation.append(a);
            equation.append( "x" + SQUARED);
         }
         if (b != 0)
         {
            if (b < 0)
            {
               if (a==0)
                  equation.append("-");
               else
                  equation.append(" - ");
                  b = -b;
            }
            else
               equation.append(" + ");
            if (b!=1 && b!= -1)
               equation.append(b);
            equation.append("x");
         }
         if (c != 0)
         {
            if (c < 0)
            {
               if (a!=0 || b!=0)
                  equation.append(" - ");
               else
                  equation.append("-");
                  c = -c;
            }
            else
               equation.append(" + ");
            equation.append(c);
         }
      }

      // erase leading +
      if (equation.length() > 2)
      {
         char ch = equation.charAt(1);
         if (ch=='+')
         {
           equation.deleteCharAt(0);
           equation.deleteCharAt(0);
         }
      }
      return equation.toString();
   }
}


//********************************************************************
//  EquationGraphPanel.java       Authors: Lewis/Loftus
//
//  Solution to Programming Project 10.9 
//********************************************************************

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class EquationGraphPanel extends JPanel
{
   private JSlider aSlider;
   private JSlider bSlider;
   private JSlider cSlider;
   private EquationViewportPanel display;
   private JLabel equationLabel;

   private final String EQUATION_SUBSTRING = "Graph of equation y = ";

   private final int MIN_VALUE = -5;
   private final int MAX_VALUE = 5;
   private final int INIT_VALUE = 0;
   private final int TICK_SPACING = 5;
   private final int MINOR_TICK_SPACING = 1;

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Sets up the panel.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public EquationGraphPanel()
   {
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());

      add(getSliderPanel(), BorderLayout.WEST);

      display = new EquationViewportPanel();
      add(display, BorderLayout.CENTER);

      equationLabel = new JLabel(EQUATION_SUBSTRING + 0);
      equationLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
      equationLabel.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 16));
      add(equationLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Creates the sliders and slider panel.
   //-------------------------------------------------------------
   private JPanel getSliderPanel()
   {
      SliderMouseListener changed = new SliderMouseListener();

      aSlider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, MIN_VALUE, MAX_VALUE, INIT_VALUE);
      aSlider.setPaintTicks(true);
      aSlider.setPaintLabels(true);
      aSlider.setMajorTickSpacing(TICK_SPACING);
      aSlider.setMinorTickSpacing(MINOR_TICK_SPACING);
      aSlider.setSnapToTicks(true);
      aSlider.addMouseListener(changed);

      bSlider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, MIN_VALUE, MAX_VALUE, INIT_VALUE);
      bSlider.setPaintTicks(true);
      bSlider.setPaintLabels(true);
      bSlider.setMajorTickSpacing(TICK_SPACING);
      bSlider.setMinorTickSpacing(MINOR_TICK_SPACING);
      bSlider.setSnapToTicks(true);
      bSlider.addMouseListener(changed);

      cSlider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, MIN_VALUE, MAX_VALUE, INIT_VALUE);
      cSlider.setPaintTicks(true);
      cSlider.setPaintLabels(true);
      cSlider.setMajorTickSpacing(TICK_SPACING);
      cSlider.setMinorTickSpacing(MINOR_TICK_SPACING);
      cSlider.setSnapToTicks(true);
      cSlider.addMouseListener(changed);

      JPanel aPanel = new JPanel();
      aPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(aPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
      aPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black));
      aPanel.add(new JLabel("value of 'a'"));
      aPanel.add(aSlider);

      JPanel bPanel = new JPanel();
      bPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(bPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
      bPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black));
      bPanel.add(new JLabel("value of 'b'"));
      bPanel.add(bSlider);

      JPanel cPanel = new JPanel();
      cPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(cPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
      cPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black));
      cPanel.add(new JLabel("value of 'c'"));
      cPanel.add(cSlider);

      JPanel sliderPanel = new JPanel();
      sliderPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(sliderPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
      JLabel title = new JLabel("ax\u00B2 + bx + c");
      title.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 16));
      title.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
      sliderPanel.add(title);
      sliderPanel.add(new JLabel("Select values for each coefficient:"));
      sliderPanel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
      sliderPanel.add(aPanel);
      sliderPanel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
      sliderPanel.add(bPanel);
      sliderPanel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
      sliderPanel.add(cPanel);

      return sliderPanel;
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Update and equation label.
   //-------------------------------------------------------------
   private void updateEquationLabel (Equation equation)
   {
      equationLabel.setText (EQUATION_SUBSTRING + equation.toString());
   }

   //********************************************************************
   //  Represents the mouse listener class for the sliders.
   //********************************************************************
   private class SliderMouseListener extends MouseAdapter
   {
      //-----------------------------------------------------------------
      //  Redraws the graph.
      //-----------------------------------------------------------------
      public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event)
      {
         Equation equation = new Equation(aSlider.getValue(), bSlider.getValue(), cSlider.getValue());
         display.setEquation(equation);
         updateEquationLabel(equation);
         repaint();
      }
   }
}


//********************************************************************
//  EquationViewportPanel.java       Authors: Lewis/Loftus
//
//  Solution to Programming Project 10.9 
//********************************************************************

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class EquationViewportPanel extends JPanel
{
   private final int X_MIN = -10, Y_MIN = -10, X_MAX = 10, Y_MAX = 10;
   private final int REAL_WORLD_WIDTH = X_MAX - X_MIN;
   private final int REAL_WORLD_HEIGHT = Y_MAX - Y_MIN;
   private final double TICK_LENGTH = 0.2;

   private Equation equation;

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Constructor: Sets up this panel.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public EquationViewportPanel()
   {
      equation = new Equation();
      setBorder (new LineBorder(Color.black, 4));
      setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Sets the equation.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   void setEquation (Equation newEquation)
   {
      equation = newEquation;
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Converts world X coordinate to screen X coordinate.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   private int convertX (double x)
   {
      double offset = x - X_MIN;
      double result = offset * getSize().width / REAL_WORLD_WIDTH;
      return (int)Math.round(result);
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Converts world Y coordinate to screen Y coordinate.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   private int convertY (double y)
   {
      double offset = Y_MAX - y;
      double result = offset * getSize().height / REAL_WORLD_HEIGHT;
      return (int)Math.round(result);
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Draws a line in world coordinates on the screen.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   private void drawScreenLine(Graphics page, double xMin, double yMin,
      double xMax, double yMax)
   {
      page.drawLine(convertX(xMin), convertY(yMin), convertX(xMax), convertY(yMax));
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Draws a point in world coordinates on the screen.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   private void drawScreenPoint(Graphics page, double x, double y)
   {
      page.drawLine(convertX(x), convertY(y), convertX(x), convertY(y));
   }

   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Draws the graph axes and equation.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public void paintComponent(Graphics page)
   {
      page.setColor(Color.white);
      page.fillRect(0,0,getSize().width, getSize().height);

      // draw the x and y axis
      page.setColor(Color.pink);
      drawScreenLine(page, X_MIN, 0, X_MAX, 0);
      drawScreenLine(page, 0, Y_MIN, 0, Y_MAX);

      // draw tick marks
      for (int x=X_MIN; x<X_MAX; x++)
         drawScreenLine(page, x, -TICK_LENGTH, x, TICK_LENGTH);
      for (int y=Y_MIN; y<Y_MAX; y++)
         drawScreenLine(page, -TICK_LENGTH, y, TICK_LENGTH, y);

      // draw the graph of the equation
      page.setColor(Color.black);
      double x = X_MIN;
      double y;
      double stepSize = (double)(X_MAX - X_MIN) / getSize().width;
      int screenX = getSize().width;
      for (int i = 0; i <= screenX; i++)
      {
         y = equation.computeValue(x);
         drawScreenPoint(page, x, y);
         x += stepSize;
      }
   }
}
```

These are the three programs that are relevant as the other is only the driver class. I tested that the right values are obtained from the sliders by printing the values right after the graph is repainted (after line 124 of the second code block) and the values are correct however they seem to change sign when they are assigned in the Equation method (Line 024 of the first code block).

I have been trying to figure out why this is happening or a work around but can't seem to get anything to work so any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This is too much to read. Could you just post snippets of the before and after areas of code in which the error occured?

Comment: How are you running this?  I see no main method in any of the classes you posted

Answer (score 1):

In your `toString()` method you are changing the signs of `b` and `c` under some conditions. This is wrong: `toString()` is not supposed to change the state of an object.

Rewrite the `toString()` method with local variables, e.g.:

```
int local_b = b;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That has fixed the issue!

Comment: You're welcome. Consider upvoting/accepting the answer ;-)